# TYPO3 different layout in TMENU for a special UID (2 TMENU inside 1 HMENU)

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

I try to setup a Menu in TYPO3 which got a fixed layout and style. But there is one UID for which I have to set other styles and other wrappings.

I tried to use override fpr allWrap, this works well. But wrap.override won't work :(

For the reason that I have three levels inside the menu, I think about using the levelUID:1 to check which menupoint actually has to be rendered. But how can I access the LEVELUID:1 inside a Menu?

Maybe there are better / other solutions? At the moment, I splitted those two menus up into two separated scripts. This can't be as it makes a positioning inside the menu impossible.

the normal menu:

```
lib.field_mainnav = HMENU
lib.field_mainnav {
    entryLevel = 0
    excludeUidList = {$featureMenuUid}
    wrap = <ul class="sf-menu fixed" id="menu">|
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        NO.stdWrap.wrap = <span> | </span>
        NO.linkWrap = <li>|</li>
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB.allWrap = <li class="dropdown">|<ul>
        IFSUB.stdWrap.wrap = <span> | </span>
        ACTIFSUB = 1
        ACTIFSUB.allWrap = <li class="current dropdown">|<ul>
        ACTIFSUB.stdWrap.wrap = <span> | </span>
        ACT = 1
        ACT.allWrap = <li class="current">|<ul> 
        ACT.stdWrap.wrap = <span> | </span>

    }
    2 = TMENU
    2 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = |</ul></li>
        NO.linkWrap = <li>|</li>
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB.allWrap = <li class="dropdown">|<ul>
    }
    3 = TMENU
    3 < .2
    4 = TMENU
    4 < .2
}
```

And the special menu for the site with UID 155 (and all subpages of it)

```
lib.field_featurenav = HMENU
lib.field_featurenav {
    wrap=|</div></ul>
   special = directory
    special.value = {$featureMenuUid}

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        NO.stdWrap.wrap = <span> | </span>
        NO.linkWrap = <li>|</li>
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB.allWrap = <li>| <div class="sf-mega">
        IFSUB.stdWrap.wrap = <span> | </span>
        ACTIFSUB = 1
        ACTIFSUB.allWrap = <li>| <div class="sf-mega">
        ACTIFSUB.stdWrap.wrap = <span> | </span>
        ACT = 1
        ACT.allWrap = <li>| <div class="sf-mega">
        ACT.stdWrap.wrap = <span> | </span>

}
2 = TMENU
2 {
    expAll = 1
    wrap = <div class="sf-mega-section"><ul>|</li>
    NO.linkWrap = <li>a|e</li>

    IFSUB = 1
    IFSUB.allWrap = <li>|
    IFSUB.stdWrap.cObject = COA
    IFSUB.stdWrap.cObject {


    10 = TEXT
    10.field = tx_pricons_pr_icons
    10.wrap = <!!=|></i>
    20 = TEXT
    20.field = title
    20.wrap =&nbsp;|
}
}
3 = TMENU
3 {
    expAll = 1
    wrap = <li>|</li></ul></div><div class="sf-mega-section"><ul>
    NO.linkWrap = <li>|</li>
    NO.stdWrap.cObject = COA
    NO.stdWrap.cObject {


    10 = TEXT
    10.field = tx_pricons_pr_icons
    10.wrap = <!!=|></i>
    20 = TEXT
    20.field = title
    20.wrap =&nbsp;|
    }
}
4 = TMENU
4 < .2

}
```

EDIT: I think I should do something like this:

```
    NO{

        linkWrap = <li>|</li>
        if{ 
            value.data = leveluid : 1 
            IsInList = {$featureMenuUid}
            stdWrap.Wrap = do another kind of wrap|to this element
        } 

    }
```

How can I prove the leveluid :1. and if it matches the featureMenuId do an override.

Is there no possibility to get the Leveluid : 1 of the actual {field:uid} ?

This would be solving my problem but I found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using a case object with the key on the uid?

Like this:

```
lib.nav = HMENU
lib.nav {

    entryLevel = 0

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1

        NO = 1
        NO.stdWrap.wrap = <span class="foo bar">|</span>
        NO.stdWrap.override.cObject = CASE
        NO.stdWrap.override.cObject {
           key.field = uid

           18 = TEXT
           18 {
               field = title
               wrap = <span class="special">|</span>
           }               

        }

    }

}
```

Answer to your comment:

Maybe cou can check the current rootline level of the page?

Like this:

```
key.cObject = TEXT
key.cObject {

    data = level

}
```

With data = level you will get the current level of the page.

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/DataTypes/Gettext/Index.html#level

**Edited Answer to my comment:  (Aug 28 at 19:35)**

```
NO {

    wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    wrapItemAndSub.override = <li class="otherWrap">|</li>
    wrapItemAndSub.override.if { 
        value = {$featureMenuUid}
        equals.field = uid
    } 

}
```

What you should know, is that

```
wrapItemAndSub
```

is from type stdWrap.

And

```
linkWrap
```

is NOT from type stdWrap. So you cant use any stdWrap property there. Thats because i used wrapItemAndSub.

I hope I explained it clearly enough.

If I gave a totally wrong answer, just let me know..

Comment: Hey, thats a good Idea. Maybe I can access the Uid of the Level:0 page while creating the menu? So I can decide what to do with level 1,2 .... without knowing theese uids. (IF page is child of the needed Level:0 uid then ....) IS there a possibility? I only found the conditions which won't work inside {} and only take effect for the active pid.

Comment: See my answer.. Maybe this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will check it out and get back to you. Cheers

Comment: ok, i think ii need your Help :):) After testing around, I think the best and hopefully working solution would be the one which I added to my question above. Maybe you can help me get it running?

Comment: Maybe i dont understand your problem.. But i think you make it to complicated..

If you want to wrap in a different way if the uid is == xy then just do the following (see my edited answer...)

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for your support. Finally, I think I will have to set in inside a userfunc. There I can built my menü on my own which makes me very flexible. I thought I can handle it in Typoscirpt but there are certain problems. I will post my solution when it's done.

Comment: At least, TS wasn't so flexible ... In the end, I switched to userFunc and set it up directly with php which works pretty nice.

Comment: Haha okay. Nice to hear that you completed your task :) ..
Userfuncs are sometimes a good solution :)

Comment: Yeah. normally, I do everything with Typoscript. But this time, I ended up in Php and built the menu from the scratch and on my own. It works perfect and userFunc was the optimal solution for the reason that BE Users can handle Pids normal without having an eye on an extenson or soth like that.